# How to avoid building the docker image if stage is skipped?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline has a condition, wherein it runs the `Node` stage only if the branch is `master`. My problem is that the `node:8` image is pulled by docker even if the stage is skipped. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Node') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'node:8' }
            }
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node -v'
            }
        }
        stage('Maven') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'maven:3' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -v'
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The when condition is evaluated on the agent. That's why the image is pulled. However, you can change this behaviour by using the beforeAgent option:

```
when {
    beforeAgent true
    branch 'master'
}
```

This will cause the when statement to be evaluated before entering the agent and should avoid pulling the image.

Comment: Thanks, didn't saw that in any example read in the last 6 months :)